# why native android mediaplayer does not support HLS but web browser does

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to implement an android app that read video stream via internet however I've got error when playing it. It rejected with error code (1, -4) which look like did not able to support the format.

I tried parse along the URL on the android web browser and it was able to read it and video shown nicely. So the question is, why web browser able to decode the stream but MediaPlayer not? What is the possible solution I can use?

Thx for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your test-device, my best guess is that the browser supports 'Flash', which it is using to stream your HLS. Native Android has a lot of problems with streaming HLS

Check out the following link for more information:

http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/